# Realm Query in multiple table

Tags: android, realm

I have two tables in Realm database. User table has a column "Tag" and Detail table has a column "description". I want to perform a search in a way that when user type something, it should get searched first in user table and then in detail table and then show the combined result. 
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The answer depends on how you want to display it and using what view.

Comment: I want to know the query..how we can query in triple table..I have to show the result in list

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34976540/2413303

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thanks for the Help!! In the solution provided the search is being done in only in Single table i.e command table..My problem is that I have to do the search in two tables and then combine the result.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Can you suggest me how can i use bidirectional link in my realm database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot combine the result of two queries. Instead your data model should use [relationships](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#relationships).