# Is there a way to conditional sort in two fields in Realm?

Tags: android, realm, realm-list

I have a Rating Realm objects list as Follows:

```
public class RatingRealmObject extends RealmObject {

    @SerializedName("average")
    private float average;
    @SerializedName("raters")
    private int raters;

    public float getAverage() {
        return average;
    }

    public void setAverage(float average) {
        this.average = average;
    }

    public int getRaters() {
        return raters;
    }

    public void setRaters(int raters) {
        this.raters = raters;
    }
}
```

I want to sort the RealmResultList by descending order of average but the number of raters should be greater than or equal to 5.

e.g. If we have two recipes as A and B.

- A has average rating 4, and no. of raters are 8 and,
- B has average rating 5 and no. of raters are 4

then after sort, A should come first in the list.

Any help how to make the condition in realm query.

Comment: So you still want all Rating's with less than 5 raters in the list, but they should just be at the bottom (also sorted) ?

Comment: @ChristianMelchior Yes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975080/complexe-sorting-for-search-in-realm/34976540#34976540

Comment: @EpicPandaForce , it's not useful for my problem.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior, I have tried to sort Using Comparator in the unmanaged realm objects but realm.copyFromRealm(recipeRealmResult) Freezing my UI  Thread.I have around 30k objects. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution would be to concatenate two RealmResults together to get the sort you want, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975080/complexe-sorting-for-search-in-realm/34976540#34976540).

---

Another solution would be that if you extend your schema with an additional field

```
public class RatingRealmObject extends RealmObject {
    @Inedx
    private float average;

    private int raters;

    @Index
    private int hasOverFiveRaters; // 0 or 1 like a TINYINT in SQLite

    public float getAverage() {
        return average;
    }

    public void setAverage(float average) {
        this.average = average;
    }

    public int getRaters() {
        return raters;
    }

    public void setRaters(int raters) {
        this.raters = raters;
        this.hasOverFiveRaters = raters >= 5 ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Because now [you can do](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#findAllSortedAsync-java.lang.String:A-io.realm.Sort:A-)

```
realm.where(RatingRealmObject.class)
     .findAllSortedAsync(
         new String[] {"hasOverFiveRaters", "average"}, 
         new Sort[] { Sort.DESCENDING, Sort.DESCENDING });
```

**P.S.:** `realm.copyFromRealm()` copies every single element from the Realm (in your case, on the UI thread) and therefore removes lazy evaluation, it is generally not needed nor recommended unless you are trying to create a detached modifiable object or want to send the RealmObject through GSON.

Comment: how to call setter method as I am using GSON library?

Comment: I always have separate objects for the API response and for the Realm schema; but otherwise you can make GSON do anything you want using a `TypeAdapter`

Answer (score 1):

You could define a `weight` field in your `RatingRealmObject`, and compute the `weight` whenever you set `average` or `raters`. Then the solution will be just as simple as sorting by the `weight`.

Some example:

```
public class RatingRealmObject extends RealmObject {
    private float average;
    private int raters;
    @Index
    private float weight;

    private void computeWeight() {
        // This is for showing the idea, you need to change how to calculate the weight depends on your requirement.
        weight = raters / 5 + average;
    }

    public float getAverage() {
        return average;
    }

    public void setAverage(float average) {
        this.average = average;
        computeWeight();
    }

    public int getRaters() {
        return raters;
    }

    public void setRaters(int raters) {
        this.raters = raters;
        computeWeight();
    }
}
```

Then you could just have `realm.where(RatingRealmObject.class).findAllSortedAsync("weight");`

Answer (score 0):

@EpicPandaForce  and  @beeender Thank you guys, You both helped me alot to solve this problem.
As I am using GSON library for the deserialization so as per GSON guidelines setter method does not call. So additional field computation in Rating object didn't work for me.

I have solved my problem by the first solution provided by @EpicPandaForce.

```
List<RecipeRealmObject> ratingMoreThan5List = recipeRealmResult.where().greaterThanOrEqualTo("rating.raters", 5).findAllSorted("rating.average", Sort.DESCENDING);
                    List<RecipeRealmObject> ratingLessThan5List = recipeRealmResult.where().lessThan("rating.raters", 5).findAllSorted("rating.average", Sort.DESCENDING);
                    List<RecipeRealmObject> ratingNullList = recipeRealmResult.where().isNull("rating").findAll();

                    List<RecipeRealmObject> recipeList = new ArrayList<>();
                    recipeList.addAll(ratingMoreThan5List);
                    recipeList.addAll(ratingLessThan5List);
                    recipeList.addAll(ratingNullList);
                    onCompleteListener.onSearchComplete(recipeList);
```

Comment: `setter method does not call. So additional field computation in Rating object didn't work for me.` and this is why I always recommend separate objects for RealmObject and API response; otherwise a `registerTypeAdapter` would also work