# How sort by date in RealmResults

Tags: android, sorting, realm

There are fields for storing the **date**. Some fields have a **date,** and some fields are empty (without a date). I need to sort in such a way that at the beginning of the list there are fields with a **date** in ascending order. And at the end of the list, there were fields without a date.

A normal sort places the fields without a date at the top of the list.

```
RealmResults<Task> results = mRealm.where(Task.class).findAll()
                .sort(Task.TARGET_DATE, Sort.ASCENDING);
```

How can I arrange sorting so that the fields without a date are at the end of the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm currently (v4.2.0)  don't supports feature to specify where will be NULL values placed (beginning/end).

Only way how you can achieve this, is create two separate Realm Queries. Take a look at similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34976540/2144352).

```
//sorted result without date equal null
RealmResults<Task> results_sorted = mRealm
            .where(Task.class)
            .isNotNull(Task.TARGET_DATE)
            .findAll()
            .sort(Task.TARGET_DATE, Sort.ASCENDING);

//result containing only Tasks with null date
RealmResults<Task> results_null = mRealm
            .where(Task.class)
            .isNull(Task.TARGET_DATE)
            .findAll();
```

Then you can merge result to unmanageable `List<Task>` or wrap them to `List<RealmResults<Task>>` and attach listener for each result set.

Comment: I know about this method, but I hoped to learn a simpler solution. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Sadly, there is none yet. They have marked this as future enhancement. https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3209