# Merge two queries, keep auto-update

Tags: android, realm

I am using Realm and I need to merge two RealmQuery or two RealmResults and send it as one object to a RealmBaseAdapter with auto-update. I have not yet figured out a way to do this. Is this problem even solvable as of Realm Java 5.0?

Comment: You have to do it yourself but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975080/complex-sorting-for-search-in-realm-union-of-multiple-realmresults for inspiration

Comment: Thank you, that helped me solve it.